# Regex: Match all newlines except first ones

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have this block of text:

```
* hello

  
world



hello again
```

Using RegEx in Javascript, how do I replace all - but except the first one - new lines between paragraphs with `\` in all platforms?

So effectively the result would be,

```
* hello

\
world

\
\
hello again
```

Comment: Can you use lookarounds?

Comment: I need support in all platforms, and Safari doesn't support lookbehind :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a look-behind assertion to account for the preceding empty line which should remain untouched. This needs no callback, and makes no assumption about the kind of newline character (`\r` or `\n` or combination) -- it just relies on the `^` and `$` line-delimiting anchors:

```js
const s = `* hello

  
world



hello again
`;

const res = s.replace(/(?<=^ *$\s+?^) *$/gm, "\\");
console.log(res);
```

See execution time comparison on [JSBench](https://jsbench.me/4olc7t78ht/1):

When you need support for platforms that do not fully implement ECMAScript 2018, then you could opt to first trim the lines of trailing white space, and then apply the following regex-based replacement:

```js
const s = `* hello
   
  
world
   
  
   
hello again
`;

const res = s.replace(/[ \t]+$/gm, "").replace(/^\s+?$/gm, "$&\\");
console.log(res);
```

If you are certain your input does not have any lines with only white space, then you can omit the first `replace` call...

Comment: The second solution is very nice.

Comment: Thanks! Look-behind is not supported in Safari though.

Comment: Safari apparently never implemented ECMAScript 2018 fully, and we are already 4 versions further down the road! Was your question to have support for ECMAScript 2017?

Comment: Cuz looking at this https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind, lookbehind is not supported in Safari.

Comment: Yes, it is a known shortcoming of Safari. They don't fully support ES2018. I added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) a non-newline (the [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) normally) and an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) newline before and use a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?retiredLocale=de) to check if *first group* is set. If so, return full match, else prepend backslash to newline.

```js
const s = `* hello


world



hello again`;

const res = s.replace(/(.\n?)?\n/g, (m0, m1) => m1 ? m0 : '\\\n');

console.log(res);
```

- to prevent a possible match at the beginning, use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(.\n?)?(?!^)\n`
- taking lines with horizontal space into account: `(^[ \t]*|\S\n?)?[ \t]*(?!^)\n`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.split()` to keep everything that shouldn't be converted to a `\`, then use `.map()` to convert all the empty space into `\`s, then recombine the lines:

```js
s = `* hello


world



hello again`;

s = s.split(/.*?(?<=\n)\n/g).map(x => x === '' ? '\\' : x).join('\n');
console.log(s)
```

I benchmarked this answer against [bobble bubble's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74941666/13376511) in [JSBench](https://jsbench.me/) and found mine to be slightly faster.

Comment: I think you should use a representative dataset to mimic the real performance of the regex and the code. Or write a few tests to see how the pattern performs against different string lengths and lines and edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a [lookbehind assertion](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in JavaScript, you could match a newline and then check that what is directly to the left of the current position is a character (without a newline) followed by 3 or more newlines.

```js
const s = `* hello


world



hello again`;

const regex = /\n(?<=.\n{3,})/gm;

console.log(s.replace(regex, "\\\n"));
```